# Why void_t doesnt work in SFINAE but enable_if does

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I was trying to understand how `SFINAE` works and I was experimenting with this code

```
#include <type_traits>

struct One { 
  using x = int; 
};
struct Two { 
  using y = int; 
};

template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::x>* = nullptr>
void func() {}
template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::y>* = nullptr>
void func() {}

/*template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::x, typename T::x>>* = nullptr>
void func() {}
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::y, typename T::y>>* = nullptr>
void func() {} */



int main() {
  func<One>();
  func<Two>();
}
```

**The commented code works but the first doesn't**.  The compiler gives me errors saying that there is a redefinition and that template argument deduction failed.  Could someone explain why this happens?  The two `void_t`s should be independent right?  Since one line checks for `x` and the other for `y`.  How can I fix?

Comment: Note that this works with the [`make_void` trick](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iiNGJAqXnq35HlJP).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be related to [CWG issue #1980](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1980) *(credits to [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) for correcting me)*.

As a workaround you can define `void_t` as:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

[*(from cppreference)*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iiNGJAqXnq35HlJP)

Comment: Whoa this problem has still not been fixed in the new installations of C++17 on gcc?

Comment: Apparently not. :(  I do see a difference on g++ 7.1.0 between the standard `void_t` and the above `void_t`.

Comment: @Whoami: I am surprised as well. If my answer is indeed correct, this is quite sad

Comment: @VittorioRomeo they could have at least used the make_void trick in the library..

Comment: @VittorioRomeo sorry but could you confirm to me once that they have not used the make_void trick in the library?  I am not sure where to check

Comment: @Whoami: the sources for libstdc++ and libc++ are publicly available, there are some mirrors on GitHub.

Comment: @Whoami: added links in my answer.

Comment: `std::void_t` is specified as `template <class...> using void_t = void;`

Comment: Yeah, those definitely aren't compiler bugs. LEWG issue?

Comment: This is not 1558. This has to do with declaration matching, i.e., whether the two `func` definitions actually declare distinct function templates or the same one. Closer to 2037.

Comment: @T.C.: interesting, all the hints seemed to point to 1558 and the `make_void` workaround. I tried my best, apologies for the possible misinformation. Would like to know why this is not related to 1558 though.

Comment: "all the hints seemed to point to 1558"? Not to me. First, you don't get anything like "ambiguous overload", which would be an indication that SFINAE's not kicking in; instead, you get "redefinition". Second, if you remove one of the two `func`s, then the remaining one gets called - or yield an error - appropriately. That's also not consistent with a SFINAE problem. Finally, just having the two definitions of `func`, without any calling, is sufficient to trigger the error. Once again, that's not consistent with a SFINAE problem.