# Nesting std::void_t, std::enable_if and pack expansion

Tags: c++, sfinae

I wanted to have a variadic template that is enabled 
only if all template parameters are of integral types. 
My solution below, which nests `std::void_t`, 
`std::enable_if`, `std::is_integral` and pack expansion, 
works as expected in gcc 8.3.0, 
but not  in clang 8.0.0-3 (the code compiles, but 
in clang substitution succeeds, when it should fail,
as indicated in comments below). 
In both cases I compiled with

```
 c++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
```

where c++ is g++ or clang++.

I wonder if this is related to a defect 
mentioned on [cppreference documentation of `std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t), 
or rather this is an error in my design.

In other words: is my simple SFINAE correct in principle?

I also noticed, that replacing `std:void_t<...>` 
by `typename Voidify<...>::type`
with

```
template<typename ... >
struct Voidify{ 
    typedef void type;
};
```

makes both programs behave as the gcc version with `std::void_t<...>`

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template< typename ... TArgs
         , std::void_t<  std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v<TArgs> >... >* =nullptr
        >
void f(TArgs... )
{
    std::cout << __func__<< " substitution succeeded\n";
}

void f(...)
{
    std::cout <<__func__<< " substitution failed\n";
}


int main()
{
    f();  //fails

    f(3); //succeeds
    f(3,4,5,6);//succeeds
    f(3,4,5,6,8); //succeeds

    f(3.5); //fails in gcc, succeeds in clang; this one succeds in clang even for 
            // non-variadic version of a template

    f(3,4,3.5); //fails in gcc, succeeds in clang
    f(3,4,3.5,5); //fails in gcc, succeeds in clang

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why void\_t doesnt work in SFINAE but enable\_if does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845945/why-void-t-doesnt-work-in-sfinae-but-enable-if-does)

Comment: BTW, `std::enable_if_t` is enough, `std::void_t` adds nothing here (except issue before CWG).

Comment: @Jarod Really? Could you please show, how to expand the pack without std::void_t, and without fold-expression?

Comment: @DavisHerring, so you are saying that this is a compliler issue, and my code is correct SFINAE?

Comment: `template< typename ... TArgs
         , std::enable_if_t<(std::is_integral_v<TArgs> && ...), int> = 0>
void f(TArgs... )`. fold expression is C++17

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks, but I was thinking that this can be done without fold expression.

Comment: @Adrian: It’s an open language issue because the specification isn’t clear—although the existence of the standard library feature would tend to suggest that we expect it to work (more than once per template).  (Incidentally, it doesn’t seem good that `f()` is rejected: all 0 of its arguments are integral.  You need an *argument* to be fed to an ellipsis in order to have its disfavored conversion apply.)

Comment: @DavisHerring OK, thanks -- that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: It can be done, with extra "helper". In C++14, you might abuse of `std::min({std::is_integral_v<TArgs>...})`.

Comment: @Jarod42. Wow! That is clever :)