# C++ SFINAE not failing

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Code:

```
#include <iostream>


using std::nullptr_t;

template<typename... T>
using nullptr_vt = nullptr_t;

struct not_addable{};


template<
  typename T, 
  nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> TSfinae = nullptr>
bool test_addable(int)
{ return true; }

template<typename>
bool test_addable(...)
{ return false; }


int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  std::cout << test_addable<int>(0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << test_addable<not_addable>(0) << std::endl;

  // Gives error ("invalid operands to binary expression"):
  // nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<not_addable>() + std::declval<not_addable>())> a{};
}
```

I thought this would print:

```
true
false
```

, but it doesn't. It prints:

```
true 
true
```

. At least on https://repl.it/@Hrle/sfinaetemplatesuccess.


I thought that `nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>` from the first overload would be an error for `not_addable` and it would discard it from the overload set, thus choosing the second overload.


Does the compiler have the ability to discard the type of `TSfinae` if there is a default?

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, it would be that the compiler being used there (I can't access it to see for myself), doesn't resolve the [issue mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845945/why-void-t-doesnt-work-in-sfinae-but-enable-if-does). And trying the proposed fix on an old version of Clang, does the trick https://wandbox.org/permlink/8pOrfXpPj0nQA4Of

Comment: fwiw, I can reproduce your outcome with gcc, but clang is `true false` https://godbolt.org/z/KjdecT

Comment: on gcc if you modify `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> TSfinae = nullptr` to `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>* TSfinae = nullptr` it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that `nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>` from the first overload would be an error for not_addable and it would discard it from the overload set, thus choosing the second overload.

The idea is actually fine, the problem is just with GCC and `nullptr_vt`

This line:

```
nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> TSfinae = nullptr
```

works where you don't want it to on GCC 10.2 but is correct on Clang 11.0.1. Changing it to

```
nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> *TSfinae = nullptr
```

is correct on both, as are the simpler

```
typename TSfinae = nullptr_vt<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>
typename _ = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())
```

And finally the make_void trick

```
template<typename... T> struct make_nullptr_vt { using type = nullptr_t; };

template<typename T>
using nullptr_vt = typename make_nullptr_vt<T>::type;
```

fixes the original version on GCC as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason I'm not going for the simpler solutions is because the user can put whatever they want there (as far as I know) and it will work. The last one is the one I like the most, because I have to do the least amount of modifications in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explain the problem, and it does not pretend to be better than @Useless answer, but it is an alternative solution I find convenient.

I replace the `typename` by an integer in order to save a bit of writing, and use the comma operator in order to enumerate many conditions if necessary.
Of course, an alias declaration with `using` can help increase readability when the same conditions have to be used many times.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @StoryTeller comment, if we declare an `operator,` that combines with the last `1`, then that `1` will be consumed and we can emit instead in `decltype()` a type that will make SFINAE fail.
He suggests inserting a `void()` in the sequence of conditions just before the `1`.
Actually, it is not possible to declare an `operator,` without a right-hand-side operand; thus nothing will combine with this `void()` and finally `1` will be emitted in `decltype()`.
It's not as minimal as just `1`, but it's safer.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A operator+(A r);
  A operator-(A r);
  A operator,(int r); // try to mislead SFINAE
};

struct B
{
  B operator+(B r);
  // no -
};

struct C
{
  // no +
  // no -
};

template<
  typename T, 
  decltype((std::declval<T>()+std::declval<T>()),
           void(),1) =1>
bool test_add(int)
{ return true; }

template<typename>
bool test_add(...)
{ return false; }

template<
  typename T, 
  decltype((std::declval<T>()+std::declval<T>()),
           (std::declval<T>()-std::declval<T>()),
           void(),1) =1>
bool test_add_sub(int)
{ return true; }

template<typename>
bool test_add_sub(...)
{ return false; }

template<typename T>
using has_add =
  decltype((std::declval<T>()+std::declval<T>()),
           void(),1);

template<typename T>
using has_add_sub =
  decltype((std::declval<T>()+std::declval<T>()),
           (std::declval<T>()-std::declval<T>()),
           void(),1);

template<
  typename T,
  has_add<T> =1> 
bool test_add2(int)
{ return true; }

template<typename>
bool test_add2(...)
{ return false; }

template<
  typename T, 
  has_add_sub<T> =1>
bool test_add_sub2(int)
{ return true; }

template<typename>
bool test_add_sub2(...)
{ return false; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "test_add<int>(0) " << test_add<int>(0) << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add<A>(0)   " << test_add<A>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add<B>(0)   " << test_add<B>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add<C>(0)   " << test_add<C>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub<int>(0) " << test_add_sub<int>(0) << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub<A>(0)   " << test_add_sub<A>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub<B>(0)   " << test_add_sub<B>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub<C>(0)   " << test_add_sub<C>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add2<int>(0) " << test_add2<int>(0) << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add2<A>(0)   " << test_add2<A>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add2<B>(0)   " << test_add2<B>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add2<C>(0)   " << test_add2<C>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub2<int>(0) " << test_add_sub2<int>(0) << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub2<A>(0)   " << test_add_sub2<A>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub2<B>(0)   " << test_add_sub2<B>(0)   << '\n';
  std::cout << "test_add_sub2<C>(0)   " << test_add_sub2<C>(0)   << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok actually, I like this even more than the accepted answer (it will remain accepted as it solves the issue). I switched to the decltype(expression, nullptr) = nullptr form in my templates. It was quite easy, it looks cleaner and @Useless answer would break my code in certain situations for which I had to introduce workarounds.

Comment: If I was malicious (or just short sighted), I'd throw into this a type that has an `operator,` (yes a comma) overload. You can make it hardier by replacing each `1` with `void(), 1`. This will force the use of the built-in comma.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for the good catch. I edited accordingly.